# How do I root my Chinavasion TechPad 7" Tablet android tablet?

Tags: rooting, tablet

I have a TechPad 7" Tablet from Chinavasion, S3C6410 Android 1.6;

None of the generic rooting methods work.

Any ideas?

Comment: So Chinavasion is a legitimate site then...I thought it was too good to be true and a scam

Comment: @Simon -- legitimate, yes. But their customer service involves your paying $35+ to send back items to china for repair/exchange;  Worse than none!

Comment: I came across that website about a year ago, didnt really believe it, I came across this recently http://android-sale.com/, so must be legitimate then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Droid2Bootstrap.apk was able to root it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the post entitled [Rooting an unbranded tablet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28937/rooting-an-unbranded-tablet) by AdemC on September 7, for further information that maybe helpful to you