# Rooting an unbranded tablet

Tags: rooting, tablet

I bought one of these simple cheap Chinese no-name tablets: HDMI, Bluetooth, HD display, dual-core CPU. Unfortunately, it came without official Google apps such as Market and Gmail. I tried different ways to install these apps. Every time I got a Force Close error.

I'm using Ubuntu as my workstation and looked with adb for the device. Found one, good! The command `lsusb` gives me

```
Bus 001 Device 031: ID 18d1:4e22 Google Inc. Nexus S (debug)
```

I've tried obtaining root access on this device, without any success. Information about the hardware is attached as a screenshot, made with Quadrant Benchmark.

[image: screen shot]

I have tried these tools:

- SuperOneClick
- UniversalAndroot
- EasyRootICS

BusyBox is installed but without su. Cannot remount /system, because its not permitted.

Cannot login with adb root, it fails with the following message

```
> adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

Comment: You can try http://xray.io/dl for additional exploits (it's a security tool by a well-known researcher (J.Oberheide from DuoSecurity). It checks for common vulnerabilities. Also: Do you have a means to boot into recovery and/or fastboot mode? The recovery might come with root access and `fastboot boot boot.img` gives you the ability to start a custom boot image that can give you root (if the bootloader is unlocked). Generally, those cheap tablets have weak security.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know what device you have, it's hard to get any assistance.

Without any warranties of success, and without assuming any responsability by what may happen to your device, I can suggest that you visit [UnlockRoot](http://unlockroot.com/), known to work with tons of devices, may became a solution for yours.

The process is done with [three steps](http://unlockroot.com/guide.html):

> 1. Your device must be in USB Debugging mode. Turn it on, go to Settings-> Applications-> Development and check the box.（[Look Here](http://www.unlockroot.com/guide/guide.htm)）
> 2. Connect your device to your PC, Run UnlockRoot.exe.
> 3. Click "Unlock Root", enjoy!

And it's [reported](http://unlockroot.com/help.html) to work quiet well, see last entry labeled "What are the Risks of Rooting?".

The [FAQ](http://unlockroot.com/faq.html) section is also quiet useful.

### Read the documentation from the website and proceed at your own risk.

Comment: This will not work with ICS, as it says in its FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

You will really struggle finding a way to root a tablet running ICS, especially a 'no brand' one.

I have had the same issue with an Arnova Gbook.

Unfortunately, the answer to your question is that it would be very difficult, and maybe even impossible, unless a *new* ICS root exploit comes out, as Google patched the main one in Android 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

try using VROOT, i've purchased a unbanded phone, (actually locally branded). Using VROOT i was able to get it rooted, now i am looking for a method to install CWM Recovery, and you just gave me a idea.. Thanks and i hope it works for you too !!

Comment: Please add a link to this app; I can't find it on the Google Play app store. Thanks!